# How to add svg in email template

Tags: svg, html-email

I need to add a svg in email’s html.

I tried placing the svg directly in the code, but the icon doesn’t render.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-227 241 225.3 224.1" style="enable-background:new -227 241 225.3 224.1;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path class="dice-1" d="M-132,241h-72.3c-12.4,0-22.6,10.2-22.6,22.6V336c0,12.4,10.2,22.6,22.6,22.6h72.3c12.4,0,22.6-10.2,22.6-22.6
    v-72.3C-109.4,251.2-119.6,241-132,241z M-195.3,340.5c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6c0-7.5,6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6
    c7.5,0,13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6C-181.8,334.4-187.9,340.5-195.3,340.5z M-195.3,286.2c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6
    c0-7.5,6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6c7.5,0,13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6C-181.8,280.1-187.9,286.2-195.3,286.2z M-168.2,313.3
    c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6c0-7.5,6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6s13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6C-154.7,307.3-160.7,313.3-168.2,313.3z M-141.1,340.5
    c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6c0-7.5,6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6c7.5,0,13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6C-127.5,334.4-133.6,340.5-141.1,340.5z
     M-141.1,286.2c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6c0-7.5,6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6c7.5,0,13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6C-127.5,280.1-133.6,286.2-141.1,286.2
    z"/>
  <path class="dice-2" d="M-24.3,347.5h-72.3c-12.4,0-22.6,10.2-22.6,22.6v72.3c0,12.4,10.2,22.6,22.6,22.6h72.3
    c12.4,0,22.6-10.2,22.6-22.6v-72.3C-1.7,357.7-11.9,347.5-24.3,347.5z M-87.6,447c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6
    c0-7.5,6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6c7.5,0,13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6C-74.1,441-80.1,447-87.6,447z M-60.5,419.9c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6
    c0-7.5,6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6s13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6C-46.9,413.8-53,419.9-60.5,419.9z M-33.4,392.8c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6
    s6.1-13.6,13.6-13.6s13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6S-25.9,392.8-33.4,392.8z"/>
</svg>
```

I also tried storing the svg in the public folder and display the svg like the following

```
<img src=“/Facebook.svg” />
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What email are you testing in? Gmail doesn't support much: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=svg

Comment: @Nathan, tested in hotmail

Comment: Hotmail? Surely that's done with now?! Do you mean Outlook.com?

Comment: Have you tried adding the svg like you would a normal picture? via `<img>` tag

Comment: @Nathan, yes, outlook.com.

Comment: @Nathan, I tried storing the svg in the public folder, and then use img tag to display it like <img sec=“/test.svg” />, but svg is not rendering.

Comment: Can you add the code to the question that you tried? It should just work. Test if your folder is the issue by using an external SVG e.g. `<img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />` (that's an svg)

Comment: @Nathan, sorry for the late reply. I just updated the question. I also tested passing an svg from the internet, it’s displaying properly.

Comment: ok so the issue is with your server then